# product category not showing exacts products means it is showing less products count

Tags: magento2

> Actually i am trying to find out why category is showing less products count but backend it has more products.
>
> product category not showing exacts products means it is showing less
> products count in category grid view (Items 1-12 of 10000) in
> frontend but in admin panel it has 43000 products magento 2
>
> **If anyone have idea about it please give some suggestions.**

Comment: Hey can you check that your product's are enabled or not  and their stock status.also check are they placed in correct categorises.

Comment: yes i checked i think everything if fine almost is any problem may be related limits in backend or anything

Comment: Yes you should check limit too.

Comment: i tried this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8681#issuecomment-286422113  but not working for me